Не устанавливается Webmin на Alt Linux
Alt linux версии 10.2, пытаюсь установить скачанный пакет webmin:
rpm -ivh webmin-2.111-1.noarch.rpm
ошибка: Неудовлетворенные зависимости:
        perl(Data::Dumper) нужен для webmin-2.111-1.noarch
        perl(Digest::MD5) нужен для webmin-2.111-1.noarch
        perl(Digest::SHA) нужен для webmin-2.111-1.noarch
        perl(File::Basename) нужен для webmin-2.111-1.noarch
        perl(File::Path) нужен для webmin-2.111-1.noarch
        perl(Net::SSLeay) нужен для webmin-2.111-1.noarch
        perl(Time::Local) нужен для webmin-2.111-1.noarch
        perl(lib) нужен для webmin-2.111-1.noarch
        perl(open) нужен для webmin-2.111-1.noarch


Perl установлен:
perl -v

This is perl 5, version 34, subversion 0 (v5.34.0 (79a7b254d85a10b65126ad99bf10e70480569d68)) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi


Пытался так же ставить пакеты которые похожи по имени с требуемыми(хотя как я понимаю это классы/модули):
apt-get install perl-Data-Dumper-Concise perl-Digest-Perl-MD5 perl-Digest-SHA perl-File-PathInfo perl-Net-SSLeay perl-DateTime-Locale perl-lib-relative perl-Browser-Open


Но ошибка всё та же. Как исправить?

corelist Data::Dumper

Data for 2021-05-20
Data::Dumper was first released with perl 5.005

То есть, Data::Dumper входит в дистритубив Perl. Не могу утверждать, но очень похоже, что установлен какой-то обрезаный дистрибутив Perl, либо не находит библиотеку.

Убедитесь, что в вашем окружении есть требуемые пакеты: perl -MData::Dumper -e '1'. Если будут проблемы, то вы увидите сообщения о ошибках. Если будет проблема, то в первую очередь попробуйте переустановить дистрибутив Perl;
Если в вашем окружении проблем нет, а вы устанавливаете в каком-то другом, то убедитесь, что в том окружении, в котором вы устанавливаете переменная окружения PERL5LIB коррентно заполнена. Подробнее о переменных окружения: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#ENVIRONMENT

